# $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/n},e^{2i\pi/n})$ is not contained in any cyclotomic extension

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

> Prove that the field $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/n},e^{2i\pi/n})$ is not contained in any cyclotomic extension.

Can someone show me how to proceed?

Comment: You need $n\ge3$ for this to be true. Hint: Show that the corresponding Galois group is not abelian. What can you say about the Galois groups of subfields of cyclotomic fields?